# Does every ivar have to be in CoreData?

Tags: ios, core-data

This might be a completely dumb question, but I'm a CD noob...

I have an object that tracks rectangular points on maps by defining the top left and bottom right corners, like this...

```
@property (nonatomic) float latitudeNorth;          // same as "northwest"
@property (nonatomic) float latitudeSouth;          // same as "southeast"
@property (nonatomic) float longitudeEast;          // same as "southeast"
@property (nonatomic) float longitudeWest;          // same as "northwest"
```

Now I need to add four more points, so that we can have polys instead of pure rectangles. So I want to add this...

```
@property (nonatomic) float latitudeNorthEast;
@property (nonatomic) float latitudeSouthWest;
@property (nonatomic) float longitudeNorthEast;
@property (nonatomic) float longitudeSouthWest;
```

These data points are ephemeral and exist only as long as the app is running. They were, however, originally built in the xcdatamodeld. Is this a problem? Or am I find just adding the additional properties and using the old xcdatamodeld as-is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I depends on you complete structure.

If you have some more entities that are fetched several times and saved again, and you need every time you fetch also the ephemeral properties, you have to hold them of course in the DB.

But if you only need them while you fetched and holding the Object, you can handle them just in class and there is no need to put them into the DB.

Not every item in the DB also has to be in the extracted class ;)

But the most attributes will also be saved, because they have to be updated via other services i.e. or have to present these updates in other views. Or maybe also because you don't want to hold the attributes all the time or will fetch them again (i.e. after a tableView.reloadData) and don't want to lose the calculated results

Comment: In fact, NONE of this data *has* to be saved in the db. Quite the opposite, the first thing the app does on startup is call a JSON server and download it all from the real DB :-) So then I think I have my answer; I'll simply declare these as properties (? or simply floats?). In my .m, do I need to use @dynamic?

Comment: Nope, don't use `@dynamic`, use `@synthesized`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have other properties declared in your managed object subclass.  They won't be initialized when you load up your object from a persistent store (when you close your app and open it up again, the values will go away), but you can get around that.  However, there are better ways to do this.  For example, you can write methods that calculate the values on the spot:

```
-(float)latitudeNorthEast;
-(float)latitudeSouthWest;
-(float)longitudeNorthEast;
-(float)longitudeSouthWest;
```

In your case, all that these methods do is return one of the other property values, so this seems like the way to go.